# What is the difference between needs_proba and needs_threshold in scikit-learn make_scorer function?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, make-scorer

Difference between them is not well explained in `make_scorer` documentation. I observed that if `needs_proba` or `needs_threshold` is set to True, scoring function receives `pred_proba` instead of `y_pred`.  However, it is not possible to set them both True. It gives error as

```
ValueError: Set either needs_proba or needs_threshold to True, but not both
```

The [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html) for `needs_threshold` says:

> For example average_precision or the area under the roc curve can not be computed using discrete predictions alone.

which I understood as needs_threshold should be set to True, if scoring is average_precision or roc_auc_score. However, it works the same whether needs_threshold is True or False.

Can you help me to understand the difference between them and usage of `needs_threshold`?

Answer (score 2):

Per the note further down the docs page, `needs_threshold` tries for `decision_function` before falling back to `predict_proba`.  For rank-ordering metrics like `roc_auc_score` and `average_precision`, there won't be a difference.

I suppose you could desire a metric that takes either raw decision function output or the (calibrated?) probability outputs.  For example, in an SVC, the decision function is (signed) distance from the separating plane, which you might like to compute the average among misclassified examples of, whereas you might also want a metric that makes use of the resulting class probabilities (after a Platt calibration, which happens internally when the SVC's `probability=True`).